# Rails take each line from a text area and make it a new resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that when a user hits submit on a few lines of code - each line will become a new resource e.g.:

```
User inputs:
Code1
Code2
Code3
Code4

They hit submit

Now 4 new resources have been made for the code model
```

I read on another question that i could use the "split" method which I tried by splitting it on the "\n" however this isn't working and for some reason it trys to go to the create view and throws an error.

Here is what I have so far:

```
##Controllers/codes_controller.rb (partial)
class CodesController < ApplicationController
############################################
                  #CREATING#
############################################                  
  def new
    @code = Code.new
  end

  def create
    array2 = code_params[:code].split("\n")
    array2.each do |f|
      @code = Code.new(params[f])


    if @code.save
      flash[:notice] = "Codes added"
      redirec_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end
  end

  private

  def code_params
    params.require(:code).permit(:id, :user_id, :code, :created_at, :updated_at)
  end
end
```

My form

```
#views/codes/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @code do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :code, :label => "Codes (make sure each one is on a new line)", :input_html => { :rows => 50, :cols => 75 } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How would I make it so that this does what I am trying?

UPDATE**

For some reason the error message has changed - this is now the error I get:

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Also it seems to be saving some of the codes but it doesn't actually save any information about the code (like the actual code) but rather just creates a new code with an Id and thats it.

Comment: Why `Code.new(params[f])` and not just `Code.new(f)` ?

Comment: The text area doesn't apply newline character but uses a carriage return. So you may try to split on "\r\n" instead.

Comment: Can you please add the error you're getting?

Comment: @ManojMonga I updated the original to show you the error message

Comment: @RubyRacer I tried that but it just gives me this error now `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.`

Comment: Is there only textarea in the form? And what is the structure of the Code model? I mean which are the parameters you need to save? One more thing, you're trying to call render/redirect_to in a loop that mean it will be executed multiple times that is what the error is suggesting.

Comment: You are getting this error because you have a redirect_to or render in a foreach block!!!! This is very-very-very wrong

Comment: @ManojMonga for the code model I only need to save the actual code, an d id. Do you have a way I could fix this loop? I have tried putting an end before the if statement but now it is giving me a nilclass error.

Comment: Ok, then assign a hash: `Code.new({:code => f})`

Comment: Can you try the answer meanwhile I am adding the explanation :)

Comment: @RubyRacerI have done that and it works somewhat but only seems to be saving the last line of the code. So say I input 20 lines it will only save line 20 and ignore teh first 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problem with your code as:

- You're splitting the code params(from an textarea) on "\n" while textarea uses a carriage return ie ("\r\n").
- You're trying to call render/redirect_to in a loop that mean it will be executed multiple times that is what the error is suggesting.

So you need to split the code on the carriage return and since you want to save multiple codes at once and display the error or success message as well, you can add either add a flag which will track the failed additions or have an array `@erroneous_codes` and append the failed codes in it. At the end you can check if the array is empty that means all the codes have been added.

```
def create
  array2 = code_params[:code].split("\r\n")
  @erroneous_codes = []
  array2.each do |f|
    @code = Code.new(code: f)
    @erroneous_codes << f unless @code.save
  end

  if @erroneous_codes.blank?
    flash[:notice] = "All Codes are added successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    flash[:error] = "Some codes could not be added: #{@erroneous_codes.join(', ')}"
    render('new')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj, this worked well and did exactly what I needed. I guess ill go through it now and try to understand it all. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I have added a bit explanation, let me know if you're unclear about anything :)